# Unable to connect Xperia-Tipo to PC?

Tags: sony-xperia-tipo

For last 2 days, I am trying to connect my new Xperia-Tipo phone to PC but unable to connect. My PC's OS is Windows XP - SP3.

1. When I connect to PC, it is asking for PC companion installation.  But when I double click on Setup.exe its doing nothing.
2. So I downloaded PC companion (Version 2.1) and I tried to connect, but its not detecting my phone.

In trouble shooting its saying please check its properly connected or not. Yes its connected and my phone is charging too. I switch off my phone & tried its waste of time. If i see in my computer its not detecting any drive for USB.

Answer (score 1):

Try use some third party applications instead of PC Companion like: [Wondershare MobileGO](http://www.wondershare.com/android-manager/) or [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/en/). Both of these are free.

I recommend *Wondershare MobileGo*. It has a full functional free version and can automatically download and install the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across a solution thought I should share it on [Microsoft's Support site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817900).

The pertinent section that worked, titled "*Method 3: Disable and re-enable the USB controller*" of the above page. (For the benefit of others who do not wish to see the page, it is quoted here)

> Use Device Manager to disable and re-enable all the USB controllers.
>   This lets the controllers recover the USB port from its unresponsive
>   condition. The USB controllers represent the USB ports in Device
>   Manager. If you are not comfortable with advanced troubleshooting, try
>   the steps in the "Workaround" section.
>
> To disable and re-enable the USB controllers, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click Start, and then click Run.
>      Note If you are running Windows Vista, click Start, and then use the
>      Start Search box.
> 2. Type devmgmt.msc, and then click OK. Device Manager
>      opens.
> 3. Expand Universal Serial Bus controllers. 
>      Note You might have to scroll down the list to find this item.
> 4. Right-click the first USB controller under Universal Serial Bus
>      controllers, and then click Uninstall to remove it.
> 5. Repeat step 4 for
>      each USB controller that is listed under Universal Serial Bus
>      controllers.
> 6. Restart the computer. After the computer starts, Windows
>      will automatically scan for hardware changes and reinstall all the USB
>      controllers that you uninstalled.
> 7. Check the USB device to see whether
>      it is working. If the USB port recognizes the device and if you can
>      use the device, you are finished.

But instead of removing it and restarting, instead, I just disabled it and re-enabled it (**please note this will fail if you use a USB keyboard**).

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect from PC.
Go to Settings/Xperia/connectivity/USB connection.
Change from MTP to MSC.
Reconnect, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings > Developer Options`, tick off USB debugging, then it'll work!
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the file `wpdmtp.inf` on the Internet; this is a needed driver. After downloading it to your PC, put the file in the `Windows/inf` directory, overwriting any existing files.

Then, open the Device Manager on your PC. Go to portable devices, and re-install the controller. Look for the necessary driver in the correct folder.

Good luck. This works for me.